# I am getting intermittent error 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' does not contain a definition for 'Contains'

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net

I am getting intermittent error when executing my .NET C# code. Below is the error.

```
  Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' does not contain a definition for 'value'
```

Below is the code I am using -

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);

string value = obj.responseObject.value.token;
```

I am getting this error when I try to execute the above code -

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' does not contain a definition for 'value'
```

Please, any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It  is impossible to help you if you don't post a json you are trying to deserialize

Comment: What members does `obj.responseObject` have? Can you check that with a debugger?

Comment: @LajosArpad, as the error message makes clear, obj.responseObject is an instance of type  `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue`. You just need to look up its documentation to see which members it has ;-)

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace - actually it **is** about the JSON because Json.NET [supports dynamic runtime binding to JSON properties by name](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonDynamic.htm) via a custom implementation of [`IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/bf2e2a78e8febf0006ec647f9bde3aa5bbe0ce72/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JToken.cs#L2427).  By declaring `obj` to be `dynamic` querent is trying to use this capability.

Comment: @dbc, as i said in response to your comment underneath the question: If that is true, how is changing "value" to "Value" make it then work? https://dotnetfiddle.net/jXlxvN  I mean, the json data in the dotnetfiddle example definitely does not define any "Value" json property. Can you explain that?

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace OP's question is, why am I *getting intermittent error 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' does not contain a definition for 'Contains'*.  The reason is not because `JValue` has a property named `Value` not `value`.  It's because they are using run-time dynamic binding to JSON properties, and sometimes the JSON does not contain the structure they expect.  I.e. sometimes it's `{"responseObject" : { "value" : { "token : "some token" } } }` but occasionally `{"responseObject" : "some atomic value or null" }` which causes the error.  We need to see the actual JSON to confirm.

Comment: @dbc, ah, now i got you. I was on an entirely different track, kinda thinking, or rather assuming that OP's intention was accessing the JValue.Value property. Dang, it didn't even occur to me that they might be trying to actually access a "value" json property and not the JValue.Value property. Oh my, i am slow with horse blinkers... But muchas gracias for sticking with me and my very slow brain... :-)

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by using this code,  

dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);

string value = obj.responseObject.value.listobject.token;

I was trying to fetch the value of the field token, for example, "token" = "xyzToken"

So, that token was inside a list. I had to use method chaining to grab that value of the token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your problem** is that you are attempting to deserialize JSON that **usually** looks like the following:

```json
{"responseObject" : { "value" : { "token" : "some token" } } }
```

By using Json.NET's [dynamic runtime binding to JSON properties](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonDynamic.htm):

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
string value = obj.responseObject.value.token;
```

In cases where your code works, the JSON contains the properties you expect with the types you expect.  But when your JSON fails to confirm to your expected schema -- specifically the value of `"value"` is an atomic JSON value or `null` rather than a nested object -- then Newtonsoft's dynamic binding code will fail with the error you see.  E.g. given the following two JSON samples:

```json
{"responseObject" : { "value" : "some atomic value such as an error message" } }
{"responseObject" : { "value" : null } }
```

then `obj.responseObject.value.token` will throw a `'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' does not contain a definition for 'token'` exception.

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dQszgK).

So, what are your options for a **workaround**?

`dynamic` binding has a convenient syntax which can look enticing, however when you use `dynamic` you lose all compile-time error checking, and often find yourself with completely inscrutable errors when your objects are not exactly as you expect.  Since Json.NET's `dynamic` deserialization actually deserializes to a LINQ-to-JSON [`JToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) hierarchy, you should do so explicitly:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(response);
```

And now to access `obj.responseObject.value.token` in a fault-tolerant manner, your options include:

1. Use [`SelectToken()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm):

   ```
   var value = (string)obj.SelectToken("responseObject.value.token");
   ```

   `SelectToken()` is more fault-tolerant than dynamic binding and will simply return `null` if no token exists at the specified path.
2. Use the `JTtoken` [indexer](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Item.htm) and explicitly check that `obj["responseObject"]?["value"]` is a JSON object:

   ```
   var value = (string)(obj["responseObject"]?["value"] as JObject)?["token"];
   ```
3. As a variation of #2, you could introduce some extension methods as follows:

   ```
   public static partial class JsonExtensions
   {
       public static JObject AsJObject(this JToken @in) => @in.As<JObject>();
       public static TJToken As<TJToken>(this JToken @in) where TJToken : JToken => @in as TJToken;
   }
   ```

   and do:

   ```
   var value = (string)obj["responseObject"].AsJObject()?["value"].AsJObject()?["token"];
   ```
4. You could use [Json.NET Schema](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema) to validate your JSON before parsing.  Note however that Json.NET Schema is not free.

Demo fiddle #2 demonstrating options 1-3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RT7hU9).

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by using this code,  

dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);

string value = obj.responseObject.value.listobject.token;

I was trying to fetch the value of the field token, for example, "token" = "xyzToken"

So, that token was inside a list. I had to use method chaining to grab that value of the token.

Comment: you are correct about the dynamic object skipping compiler error checking.  I was trying to find a simple solution and not make the code too complicated.  Your answer is very excellent.